# How do I defeat Dragon Priest Nahkriin?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've been flown to a temple to kill Alduin but I'm not strong enough to get past Dragon Priest Nahkriin. He's killed me over and over in 2 shots that come faster than I can deal with and so I'm fairly sure there's nothing I can do.

However the dragon that flew me to the temple has disappeared and even if I go back to the spot he dropped me off and call him he doesn't return. I can't fast-travel from this location, either.

I don't have any previous save files as I didn't think this would be an issue. Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran off to the left, there's an area on the side where I was able to go that he wouldn't follow me to.  I just stayed in the back there and shot arrows at him.  When my health would get low, I'd go off and heal up.  He doesn't regen health so you can just sit there and peck away at him.

If you don't have a bow, maybe get close and then use the ethereal shout to go invincible and run away to the safe corner I was describing.

Kinda cheap but it seems like you're stuck.

Answer (score 9):

If I remember correctly, you will learn the storm shout right before this guy. Nail him with thunder, and he will be a walk in the park

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the Nakriin, I battled him using a 2h Ebony Sword with a simple poison applied. I used Whirlwind Sprint, Rank 2 to get to him, and then laid into him, interrupting his spells with a block-attack. Alternatively you can use your Fire breath to start with, that will do a fair amount of damage, and then you spring in and finish him off.

Answer (score 1):

When you are in the building you get storm call. When I went outside there were draugrs and dragons and I was only level 10 when I did this. There are dragons landing constantly, and there is like a broken castle right in front of you. When you go outside use storm call and go hide in the broken castle and do that over and over but storm call takes forever to recharge.  Storm call is good against nahkriin too.  Also there are elder dragons on top of the pillars and do not shoot them and they wont attack you; They will just sit there. I have only killed 5 dragon priests so try that and it will be good.

Answer (score 1):

You can drop him down the first square hole, and he'll be glitched there. Take your bow, shoot, and duck back when he fires at you.

Answer (score 1):

Do you happen to have [Spellbreaker](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Spellbreaker_%28Skyrim%29)?
It's the Daedric artifact of Peryite.
It's a shield that puts up an anti-magic ward when you block.
This shield is your best defense against magic user, so also Dragon Priests.
It even stops the shouts from the Draugr bosses in the Forbidden Legend quest.

But if you don't have this on you, you could try the tactics from other answers.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It's easy if you have lot of stamina, some armor and the fire breath shout. First sneak up or run close enough to use the fire breath on him. Then run to cover. Repeat these two and you should kill him in 2 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm only level 17, use firebreath first on the nahkriin. Then use firebreath. I have an ocrish battleaxe of burning, poison it with weak magical poison and keep hitting the target. They should die VERY quickly. Hope you've managed to do it by now. :P

Comment: If I was still struggling and trying to do it three years down the line I think I'd have more problems than just trying to defeat Nahkriin :)

Answer (score 0):

He's fighting that skeleton sorcerer right before entering the portal, I found 2 ways of dealing with him MY way I ran up the stairs an killed him before he even got the staff lvl 36 the easiest way put difficulty on novice its a noobish thing to do but it will greatly improve your chances if you aren't strong enough, I play on adept myself :P

Answer (score 0):

I just ran past him and entered the portal before it closed, you could try it.

Answer (score -1):

What I did is whirlwind speed up the stairs and attack him with the steel great sword.  I was only level 10 and I killed him in 3 minutes.  Then I took his stuff and went in the portal.

Comment: Do whirlwind spring or the steel sword have any significance? If not, this answer can be summarized as "hit him until he stops moving".

Answer (score -2):

All I did was use the Sanguine rose staff and the dremora killed him for me. easy breezy.

Answer (score -3):

I killed his piece of cake. I'm level 37 its not to high but my primary account is level 189 so I know a few things.

1.Try to use some daedric armor or ebony armor.
2.If you can use the Glass blade of flames and the Dawnbreaker.
3.Try leading Alduin on the bridge and use the Thunder storm shout
4.Stack up on extreme healing potions, you can find them at stores and ruins, ext.
5. Don't Get Killed.